# In T-SQL how can I get a column of 2-decimal points(or percentages)?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, math, arithmetic-expressions

In SQL Server 2008, I am running a report where I need to divide two columns (called `Completes` and `Prescreens`, whole integers), and then I go to Excel and get the `Prescreens` divided by the `Completes`, and turn that into a number with 2 decimal places, then convert that to a percentage. i.e. -> 0.34, then becomes 34%.

In SQL in know I probably can't get the output as "34%" but at least I'd like it as 0.34 .  So far I have:

```
cast((sq.Completes/sq.Screens ) as float ) as 'conv'
```

Completes are the smaller of numbers(usually 27, 38, etc), and Screens are bigger numbers(124, 276, etc.)

But this is outputting my column as all `0s` . How do I make it show 0.34 , 0.84, etc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
select (cast(sq.Completes as float)/cast(sq.Screens as float)) as 'conv'
```

You can also do this to round the value:

```
select round((cast(sq.Completes as float)/cast(sq.Screens as float)),2) as 'conv'
```

And finally, this to show it visually as a percentage:

```
select cast(round((cast(sq.Completes as float) /
   cast(sq.Screens as float)),2) * 100 as varchar(25)) 
   + '%' as 'conv'
```

Comment: Good, I also updated my answer to get the other format you mentioned 34%

Answer (score 2):

Pure number (it includes round)

```
cast(100.0*sq.Completes/sq.Screens as decimal(6,0)) conv
```

With percent

```
cast(cast(100.0*sq.Completes/sq.Screens as decimal(6,0)) as varchar(6)) + '%' conv
```